# Get lastModifiedDate of the current active document open in photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, complex-event-processing

I try to get the last modified date attribute of a file open in photoshop. I work with the cep framework. Does someone know how to do it please ?

Comment: Why can't you use node.js `fs.stat()`?

Comment: You should be able to access it with `var fileModifiedDate = fileRef.modified.toString();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it with xmp framework

Comment: Try to provide how you did it so others can do it as well :)

Comment: sure, this project is exactly what I needed : https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/tree/master/XmpSamplePanel